# Do I need a power strip with power-surge protection for a laptop?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, power, powerline-networking

There are simple power strips and [power strips with surge protection](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=stip%20with%20surge%20protection&t=canonical&iar=images&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fimages-na.ssl-images-amazon.com%2Fimages%2FI%2F31m-6wWOOdL.jpg) (and also with short circuit protection). Is there difference in that matter for PCs and laptops? If I use laptop I have a battery (does this protects me from such stuff) and [a power adapter on the power cord](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=laptop%20power%20adapter&t=canonical&iax=images&ia=images). May be the adapter does something, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: Yes**

For laptops and mobile electronics, I always recommend surge protectors that use resettable circuit breakers, such as Panamax's [Power360 Wall Tap](https://www.panamax.com/product/power360-6-outlet-wall-tapcharging-station-P360-DOCK) *(auto-senses under-voltage and over-voltage, auto tripping and resetting its internal breaker when required, providing a LED ring with three diagnostic lights)*.

- Using any externally powered electronics without a surge protector risks permanently damaging those electronics when a surge occurs *(it's not a matter of if, but when)*

A battery is simply there to power the device, not absorb fluctuations in voltage and amperage the way a vehicle's battery does; small fluctuations are dealt with via the AC-to-DC power adapter/brick.

- Lithium-based batteries require a very specific charging voltage and amperage range - they are not there to absorb a voltage/amperage surge, as doing so could have serious repercussions from heat damage

  - *If the battery temp rises high enough from over-voltage/current, it can melt it's hermetically sealed electrolyte which burns explosively when exposed to oxygen*

A surge would likely only fry the laptop's power brick, but whether any of the excess voltage/current could pass to the laptop is dependent on the internal design of the power brick. 
 *Surge protectors should be purchased based on Joule rating (higher Joule rating = better).*

- Surge protectors, *excluding those with resettable circuit breakers*, have a finite lifespan and can only be reliably used for a few years, usually two to three years is what most manufacturers guarantee.
- Non-resettable circuit breaker protectors are one-time use only protection items - once a surge occurs, the surge protector needs to be replaced.

Comment: If there is an electric meter with circuit breakers (like on the picture below) and a laptop with power adapter, is it enough or still necessary to have a power strip with protection?<br>https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.camtecelectrical.com.au%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2FCaravan-meter-box.jpg&f=1&nofb=1

Comment: You still need a surge protector against fast and large surges. Circuit breakers have limited capability.

Comment: @Rick To piggy back John's comment, electrical panel circuit breakers are there to protect the building's electrical wiring, not individual components _(a whole home surge protector at the panel is recommended, but its purpose is to protect large appliances only)_. Circuit breakers don't trip as soon as the current exceeds the breaker's rating - it trips when enough heat has been generated to expand the bimetal contact _(check out YouTube videos that show what happens internally with a breaker during a surge - it's not an instantaneous trip unless the current surge is significant)_.

Comment: Could you say something about 90 Joule vs 125 Joule strip (max energy of an input impulse)?

Comment: @Rick Neither would be recommended, as that's too low of a rating since Joules are the amount of energy absorption/dissipation it can handle before the MOVs _(surge protectors w/o a circuit breaker use MOVs)_ fail, passing that voltage/current onto plugged-in devices. ~1000J would be the minimum I would recommend, with the bare minimum I'd recommend being ~600J for small electronics like PCs, routers, printers, etc. [EchoGear](https://www.echogear.com/blog/how-many-joules-of-surge-protection-do-i-need/) provides a basic explanation and recommendations, such as an absolute minimum of 400J.

Comment: @Rick _Cont'd..._ MOVs _(**M**etal **O**xide **V**aristors)_ are what absorb excess voltage/current, which fail after x surge cycles or all at once w/ a large enough surge; it's for this reason surge protectors w/o resettable circuit breakers are recommended to be replaced every 2 - 3yrs. The "Protected" / "Protection" LED should be checked regularly, as it goes out when all MOVs have failed _(surge protector will still power devices, but will have no surge protection)_. Even w/ circuit breakers, a low enough surge can still pass until it generates enough heat to fully flex the bimetal contact

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, one last thing. What if a lamp in a switch doesn't work anymore, but there is a small green lamp near it, that works?

Comment: @Rick I think you're referring to one of the lights on the Surge Protector? If so, that light will either have a label next to it, or you'll need to look up the manual/call the manufacturer to determine what that light is. If it's the Protection/Protected light that's no longer turning on, the surge protector should be replaced as its MOVs have all failed due to a surge or surge cycles and it will no longer protect against surges.

Answer (score 2):

A laptop battery can protect against low level fluctuations and short term power outages and subsequent power restarts.

The AC input has a range of input voltages and the battery provides basic power to accomplish the above.

But that does not protect against a major power surge like a lightning strike. You still need a surge protector for such events.

We have (and have had) clean power here so I do not equip my laptop with a surge protector because the need does not exist (greater than 99%)